# Does the “Put hard disks to sleep when possible.” option in macOS have any affect on SSD drives?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd, sleep-wake

I completely understand the value of putting a hard disk (specifically) to sleep in some cases especially in the pre-SSD days of the past. It can save power, lower noise and such. But in the case of modern systems that are increasingly SSD-based, does this option have any value at all?

My MacBook Air (2018) running Mojave (10.14.1) has “Put hard disks to sleep when possible.” checked off by default (in **System Preferences > Energy Saver**), but this system uses an SSD.

Is this option only focused on hard disk drives and ignored by SSD drives?

I can’t imagine the internal SSD would ever “sleep” but correct me if I am wrong.

#### In short, does the “Put hard disks to sleep when possible” option have any affect on SSD drives in macOS?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to Apple:

> **Put hard disks to sleep when possible**
>
> This setting powers down the hard drive motor when you aren't reading
>   or writing files from the drive. **Solid-state drives (SSDs) don’t have
>   moving parts, so this setting doesn’t affect Mac computers that use
>   only SSDs to store data.**
>
> Consider deselecting this option if you have
>   an internal or external non-SSD drive and you use apps—for example,
>   pro audio or video editing software—that work better with continued
>   read and write access to the hard disk.

<sup>**Source:** Apple: [Use the Energy Saver settings on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT202824) [**Bold** emphasis mine]</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Solid-state drives (SSD) do not use a motorized mechanism to read or write data. For Mac computers that only include a built-in solid-state drive, this setting does not affect the built-in drive. It only applies to externally connected, mechanical drives.

Answer (score -3):

SSD vs HDD uses about 50% less of energy, so having the option turned on *will* help reduce overall power consumption.

ie - my MBP 15" 2011 has 95 Wh battery in it (when new, down to about 60-70 now), so in a hour with the option you will save some 1-2% of battery life with the option on, depending on use.

https://therevisionist.org/reviews/ssd-vs-hdd-power-consumption/
https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/950687-hdd-vs-ssd-temps-power-consumption/

Comment: That power consumption  comparison should be of "in use" state, not idle.

Comment: Yes, but idle is also not null. There are plenty of resources online that list anywhere from 30-50% power reduction for the SSD, but in my view that is still significant.

Comment: Please reread the question. It's not about comparing HDD vs SSD, it's about the effect of a power-saving option on SSDs.